# How to wait until find method has finished before doing further processing in Ember Model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model

How can I wait until my find method has finished loading the model from the backend? After the model has loaded I want to fetch additional data and decorate my movie model with that data. The request to the external api from which the additional data is fetched is based upon properties of the movie model like year and title.

```
App.Movie.adapter = Ember.Adapter.create({
  find: function(record, objectId) {
    return Ember.$.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': '',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': ''
      },
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Movie' + '/' + objectId
    }).then(function(data) {
      record.load(objectId, data);
    });
  }
});

App.MoviesMovieRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (movie) {
    return App.Movie.find(movie.movie_id);
  },

  afterModel: function(movie, transition) {
    // currently undefined, undefined
    console.log(movie.get('title'), movie.get('year'));
  }
});

App.MoviesMovieController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  contentObserver: function () {
    // fetch additional data from external api
  }.observes('content')
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Try typing a print statement at the end of the method. That will show that the method has been done

Comment: How about running your ajax call as Async: false? it will have to get an answer before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ember model, use fetch, it will return the promise, and ember will wait until resolving that model before doing the next model.

```
return App.Movie.fetch(movie.movie_id);
```

find builds up a dummy record and returns the record immediately (and populates it when the data is available), whereas fetch builds up the record, and a promise, and returns the promise, which resolves to the record when it's been populated.

They will both use the find method from the adapter.

```
App.MoviesMovieRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (movie) {
    return App.Movie.find(movie.movie_id);
  },

  afterModel: function(movie, transition) {
    // currently undefined, undefined
    console.log(movie.get('title'), movie.get('year'));
  },

  serialize: function(model){
    return { movie_id: model.get('whateverfieldhastheid')};
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the id from the dynamic url part? So the single view renders correctly after page/browser reload? And do I have to put the return statement in front of the ajax request for returning a promise or is it ok to leave off that return statement? Thx

Comment: The id and url part seems ok. But I'm getting this error message in the console: "Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object." Any idea?

Comment: you need to implement the serialize hook in your route. I'll find an example for you.

Comment: Sorry... ;-) But now there is only a white screen. Nothing gets rendered and no error message in the console. Possible reason might be the single view is a subroute of the list view? Thx

Comment: It was rendering before?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41736/discussion-between-philipp-kosel-and-kingpin2k)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to implement find() with an RSVP Promise like so:

```
App.Movie = Ember.Object.extend({

});

App.Movie.reopenClass({
    find: function(objectId) {
        return Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Movie' + '/' + objectId
            }).success(function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            }).fail(function(data) {
                reject(data);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in your Route, you can add then to your promise:

```
App.MoviesMovieRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (movie) {
        var movie = App.Movie.find(movie.movie_id); 
        movie.then(function() {
            // Gets called once the server returned loaded
            console.log(movie.get('title'), movie.get('year'));
        }, function() {
            // FailureHandler
        });
        return movie;
    },
});
```

- Note that this isn't using EmberData at all. I don't know if that was a requirement?